# Wordpress upload image size

Tags: image, wordpress

Kinda new to wordpress.. Creating my own theme. When I upload an image and put it in a post it comes out at 300x183 pixels but the original file I upload is 1800x1100 pixels. Wordpress alters my size when i upload it.This is what i get in the url on the post NDAppleProductMockUp-300x183.jpg.. It restricts the size of the image. When i go into the image properties within the post and click original nothing happens it stays at 300x183.. I have tried to work it out but can't Any suggestions guys..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, WordPress does not resize the actual image that you upload. It creates 3 smaller versions of it, leaving the uploaded image untouched. I would suggest that you create all of your images at  1800x1100 before you upload them.

Another solution would be to link to the "big-sized" image when you "Insert into Post"... unfortunately, you would have to know the filename of the large image. I check the source code and this part of the media system does not appear to be pluggable.

Another option may be to check out this plugin:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/

Answer (score 0):

This link here details how You can change what image size will be displayed

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

also when u attach to post you can set the image size in the setting
 *THE SETTING is **Before** you attach the image!*

you are trying to change an image that has already been attached (the attached image was in a mid or small size to begin with) so it is already at its original size.